# I can't find Asp.Net Web Pages Administration in webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I'm unable to see it in the dashboard even though I have .cshtml files in the root. Anyone knows what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you give us some more info regarding the issue?

Comment: In the dashboard, when you click on "Site", you should be able to see the URL of the site and the folder that contains it, plus all the stuff at the bottom, like the asp.net web pages administration. The problem is that i can see only the url and the folder (which is, as i said, in the root of webmatrix) and then only the links to the suggestions and the problems. The "asp.net web pages administration" is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The Administration feature/Package Manager was removed from version 2.0 of WebMatrix/Web Pages onwards. It was replaced by the Nuget extension within WebMatrix.